# "Key is missing data to perform the decryption" error on SAML2 LARAVEL 8

Tags: php, laravel, encryption, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

Update: We were able to solve the problem by using a different encryption method when recreating the x509 certificate

Question:
we have a weird problem with our SP / IdP Connection on our SAML2 implementation in our Laravel 8 application.

We use https://github.com/aacotroneo/laravel-saml2 based on OneLogin toolkit.

I guess the question is very similiar to the (sadly) deleted question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70447585/key-is-missing-data-to-perform-the-decryption-error-on-saml-response

We get the error "Key is missing data to perform the decryption" on our /acs endpoint. The error seems to be produced in the vendor/robrichards/xmlseclibs/src/XMLSecEnc.php file.

The error seems to be related to the x509 certificate and that it should be set correctly in the idp config - but we are relatively sure about the implementation (there is only one place to add the certificate details).

The cert seems correct, we tried to validate the cert with https://www.sslshopper.com/certificate-decoder.html and it looked good so far.

When we try the SSO with OneLogin as our IdP everything works fine.

Does anyone else had to deal with the "Key is missing data to perform the decryption" error in a similar setup?

Best regards